# I want to change a key mapping in vim while on a specific file

Tags: vim

The `autocmd` in vim is very useful when we want to for example change the key mapping according to filetype:

```
autocmd Filetype tcl map <f1> :execute "!tclsh %"<CR>
```

What I need at the moment is to change the key mapping but only on an specific filename. Is this possible?

Comment: Even in the filetype case, you should localize your changes with the `:map <buffer>`, as shown in romainl's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
autocmd BufNew,BufRead filename.ext map <buffer> <f1> :execute "!tclsh %"<CR>
```